# What is ENDIF doing in templates?

Tags: php, templates

p.s. I don't think it's too broad; it's a very particular question;

Everyone knows what is If in general; I needed in particular;

Generally - I have seen this `<?php endif; ?>` used often in website templates, and now again...

I am trying to add new regions in Drupal 7 Adaptive theme and the original code is:

```
<!-- !Main Content -->
            <?php if ($content = render($page['content'])): ?>
              <div id="content" class="region">
                <?php print $content; ?>
              </div><?php endif; ?>
```

- and I need to understand how to add my New Regions (duplicates of the original Content region) - should I use ENDIF for each new Region, or only after all regions:

  ```
            <?php if ($content = render($page['content'])): ?>
              <div id="content" class="region">
                <?php print $content; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="content2" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content2']); ?></div><?php endif; ?>

    <div class="content3" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content3']); ?></div><?php endif; ?>

    <div class="content4" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content4']); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="content5" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content5']); ?></div></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
  ```

or: All New Regions-div's Inside that ENDIF?

```
<!-- !Main Content -->
            <?php if ($content = render($page['content'])): ?>
              <div id="content" class="region">
                <?php print $content; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="content2" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content2']); ?></div>
 
    <div class="content3" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content3']); ?></div>
  
    <div class="content4" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content4']); ?></div>
    <div class="content5" style="clear:both"><?php print render($page['content5']); ?></div></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Each `if` gets an `endif`.

Comment: Please do not code if you cannot figure this out on your own

Answer (score 2):

```
if(condition):

// some scripts here

endif;
```

Is same as

```
if(condition)
{

    // some scripts here

}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: I know there are Manuals; I have no time for it; I need only Inside or For Each Div?

Comment: @user1981528: no way to answer that. you're basically saying "I have a tool. Do I need it to build my whatever?".

Comment: @user1981528 I can guarantee to you, that typing to google keywords `php if endif` is a much faster than writing this question.

Comment: @user1981528 `I have no time for it` So we should make the time for you?

Comment: I often see those templates which are using ENDIF after every quote; I have no time to study why it is needed there, just to add it between my script or after...

Comment: You should be happy I'm asking! I'm not supposed to know any php, and yet I know some!

Comment: Do you truly not know what `if` does?

Comment: Yes, I know what IF does; I need only if there is a difference if ENDIF comes after all Regions or separately after each one! And there are only 2 options; and probably I will guess which by practice! Yet - you could help me to shorten it!